# What is the correct way to start and stop thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I need to write following. When button is clicked new thread should be start. Run method is infinite loop which changes for instanse text in TextView, and when I press button again it should stop changing text. 
Please help how to do this in the correct way without dangerous methods. 
Thx in advance .

Answer (score 2):

```
private Thread t;
private String threadName;
private boolean suspended = false;

public void run() {
    System.out.println("Running " +  threadName );

    try {
        for(int i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
            System.out.println("Thread: " + threadName + ", " + i);
            // Let the thread sleep for a while.
            Thread.sleep(300);
            synchronized(this) {
                while(suspended) {
                    wait();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Thread " +  threadName + " interrupted.");
    }

    System.out.println("Thread " +  threadName + " exiting.");
}

public void start () {
    System.out.println("Starting " +  threadName );
    if (t == null) {
        t = new Thread (this, threadName);
        t.start ();
    }
}

void suspend() {
    suspended = true;
}

synchronized void resume() {
    suspended = false;
    notify();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not really clear what you want to do for me.

But I bet you can do it using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) with doInBackground and onProgressUpdate, take a look.

Comment: AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time, it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the java.util.concurrent pacakge such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and FutureTask.

Comment: I need to start infinite loop which would change text in textview .For example first time I've clicked button infinite loop starts , second time I've clicked button this loop should break. And again click -loop  starts , click - stops.

Comment: It would be perfectly good with AsyncTask as it is a pure layout work. But if you prefer, you can do it with Handler and postDelayed recursively, but than you would care a lot with activity life cycle.